# Purpose of SeDebugPrivilege for DLL injection

Tags: windows, injection

I have been recently working on a little DLL injection program in Go.
While the program works and I am able to successfully inject into a remote process, Windows permissions system still seems to elude me.
Namely, I cannot quite understand the purpose of adding SeDebugPrivilege to my current process token.
In theory, I understand that the token is:

1. Only granted to Administratos(s),
2. Allows to get an handle to a remote process with PROCESS_VM_WRITE set, so that it is possible to write to the remote process memory.

My tests so far, however, seem to go against these notions, so I was wondering if someone could shed more light on this. Here's a breakdown of what I have tried, notice that the results do not change regardless of whether UAC is enabled or not.

- If I try to inject a low-privilege process from another low privilege process (I start notepad and inject it from a non Admin terminal) I always succeed, regardless of whether I try to get the SeDebugPrivilege privilege or not.
- The same as above holds true for high privilege processes. If I start a notepad process from an Administrator console I can always inject it from the same console, no matter if I actually get the SeDebugPrivilege or not.
- I can never, in any circumstance, inject a higher privilege process, like a high privilege notepad from a low privilege shell (this, however, I expected).
- If I try to inject a SYSTEM process I can never succeed, regardless of the privilege of my starting process or whether I obtain the SeDebugPrivilege or not. Could this be because SYSTEM processes are protected from memory write as described [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-security-and-access-rights?redirectedfrom=MSDN)?

As you can see, it seems from my tests that getting the SeDebugPrivilege changes absolutely nothing regarding which process I can or cannot inject.

Of course, it might also be that the code I am using to get the privilege is wrong. I am pasting here. Notice that under no circumstance the code errors out (which is of course not a good sign necessarily).

```
func setSeDebugPrivilege() {
    // Get current process (the one I wanna change)
    handle, err := windows.GetCurrentProcess()
    defer windows.CloseHandle(handle)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Get the current process token
    var token windows.Token
    err = windows.OpenProcessToken(handle, windows.TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &token)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Check the LUID
    var luid windows.LUID
    seDebugName, err := windows.UTF16FromString("SeDebugPrivilege")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    err = windows.LookupPrivilegeValue(nil, &seDebugName[0], &luid)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Modify the token
    var tokenPriviledges windows.Tokenprivileges
    tokenPriviledges.PrivilegeCount = 1
    tokenPriviledges.Privileges[0].Luid = luid
    tokenPriviledges.Privileges[0].Attributes = windows.SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED

    // Adjust token privs
    tokPrivLen := uint32(unsafe.Sizeof(tokenPriviledges))
    fmt.Printf("Length is %d\n", tokPrivLen)
    err = windows.AdjustTokenPrivileges(token, false, &tokenPriviledges, tokPrivLen, nil, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("[+] Debug Priviledge granted")
}
```

Thanks in advanced to everyone!

Comment: You wont be needing sedebug privilage when it comes to dll injection.You would rather require it when doing token impersonation.

Comment: Also you cannot inject into some processes without being signed by microsoft,although there are tricks to subvert windows trust by faking the certificates

Comment: Hi, yeah that's what it seems like. Does that also hold for Admin to SYSTEM injection? Say I want to inject a SYSTEM process from an admin session, do I need SeDebugPrivilege?